# the program can not be started because MSVCR80D.dll is missing from your computer,try reinstalling the program to fix this issue

Tags: visual-c++

when i try to run a application developed in vc++ on windows7,i get popup window saying that"the program can not be started because MSVCR80D.dll is missing from your computer,try reinstalling the program to fix this issue."

I googled it,it says that this DDL may not be present in your system or it has been got corrupted,Now i searched this file, i get this file at 20 different folder in win7.

I am not getting which file has been corrupted or if it is missing then where it is mising?

can anybody tell in which folder ,this DDL is missing or might be corrupted?

Thanks in advance. .

Comment: Try `dumpbin /imports exefile` to see which DLL the exefile should import binary codes.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run a Debug version of your program on a machine which does not have VS installed. The MS*D.dll files are not redistributable - they are installed were VS is installed. If you want to run executables on other machines, compile them as Release. You might still need to deploy some files (depending on how you're linking to the CRT), but that won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Never ever distribute your DEBUG builds to customers. Always distribute Release build.

Yes, of course, in develoment environment having multiple machines, you may share Debug builds to other developers - provided others developers have debugging-tools (like VS) installed on their system along with Debug-binaries of shared DLLs (like MSVCRxx).

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the same computer that compiled the program? If not, you need visual studio redistributable files to run it.

Search the internet for your version of visual studio or visual c++ redist, you'll find it.

Comment: The debug DLLs are not redistributable.

Comment: I haven't worked in a windows environment for more than 2 years but as far as I remember, release builds also have that kind of dll problem. I can't try it since I don't have a working windows copy nearby, but are you sure that, for example this link http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679, installs ONLY debug dlls?

Comment: Besides, the poster might also want to run debug version, most of the projects have `#ifdef _DEBUG` all around the code and release version is much more silent. If so, running debug version of a project might yield additional information if errors occur.

Comment: Only the release build of the runtime DLLs can be redistributed, and the link you provided provides **only** release DLLs.  Yes, sometimes it is useful to install debug versions of an application on user machines, but the only way to do that and be in compliance with Microsoft's licensing terms is to install Visual Studio on that machine.  That's not to say that no one has ever copied debug DLLs onto machines for testing, but technically they're violating VS's license terms when they do so.